# Difficulty Extracting Text Content from Webpage Using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am building my first Chrome extension to quickly display information from a webpage in a popup.

To start with I would like to take the name from within two  tags which appear in the HTML as follows:

`<a href="/link-to-joe-bloggs-cv" class="name" role="heading">JOE BLOGGS</a>`

What I am trying to do is to extract "JOE BLOGGS" from the page and display it in the popup.

So far, I have the following code:

**Popup.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Joe Bloggs CV</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="popup-content">Loading...</div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Manifest.json**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Joe Bloggs CV",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Displays CV name in the popup",
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ]
}
```

**Popup.js**

```
// popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const popupContent = document.getElementById('popup-content');
  popupContent.textContent = 'Joe Bloggs';
});
```

This works, but now I would like to dynamically update the `popupContent.textContent` when I am on a different page by using the `.name` class on each individual's CV.

I tried by updating popup.js to:

```
// popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  const popupContent = document.getElementById('popup-content');
  popupContent.textContent = document.querySelector(".name").innerHTML;
});
```

However, the popup then gets stuck on "Loading..."

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Content script` file (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) which can be named `content.js`. This file will be injected into the html of the website you're visiting. Make sure to check the docs as to how to register the file in the `manifest.json`.

Inside the `DOMContentLoaded` handler function in `Popup.js` you need to send a a message to the `content.js` using the `sendMessage` function, asking for the `.name` value. Upon receiving the message, `content.js` will look up the value and send it back to `Popup.js`

```
// popup.js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, { message: "getName" }, function (response) {
            const popupContent = document.getElementById('popup-content');
            popupContent.textContent = response.name;
        });
    });
});


// content.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    // listen for messages sent from background.js
    if (request.message == 'getName') {
      let name = document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0].innerText;
      sendResponse({name});
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi there! I have created a content.js file and added the registration in manifest.json. However, when the extension is pressed it just hangs on "Loading..."

Comment: @Dan did you update the Popup.js code? I just noticed a line of code was missing in my answer (the 'const popupContent =...'). Try updating the Popup.js code again

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I updated the popup.js code and it is still doing the same thing. I get an error in Chrome saying: popup.js:7 (anonymous function)

Comment: @Dan post the whole error

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
Context
popup.html
Stack Trace
popup.js:7 (anonymous function)

Comment: @Dan there were some missing brackets in my answer (in popup.js). I updated my answer